# Plugin with id 'dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader' not found

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, plugins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qImUx.png)
I'm starting to learn flutter development. When I run the project for the first time it gives this error.

I've reinstalled android studio and flutter and dart plugins and create new project .

Answer (score 3):

In my case I got the same error after following the migration guide [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply)

The issue was an outdated version of gradle in *android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties*.
After setting the distribution url to 8.5 it worked. Do the change inside visual Studio in order to better handle the gradle migration.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-all.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the Flutter community.

What is your Flutter version? I recommend you to run the latest one – `3.16.0`. Run `flutter upgrad` to make sure you use it.

The error you're getting is likely because of some mistake in native Android build.gradle files. Please refer to [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/135392) and make sure you `android/settings.gradle`, `android/build.gradle`, and `android/app/build.gradle` files look the same as the ones in that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue when I created project on Flutter 3.16.x then running on Flutter 3.13.x (downgrade sdk using fvm)

Both work for me

- Revert to 3.16.x version
- Update `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`, follow @Bartek Pacia answer

Answer (score 0):

check your flutter SDK Path setting.

1. go to env setting
2. cilck path setting
3. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WcxW.png)

Click Move Up until the Flutter entry sits at the top of the list." <= this is most improtant!!